# Error in shadowing bucket in sync gateway

Tags: couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to connect sync gateway to couchbase server with following config.json file

```
{
   "interface":":4984",
   "adminInterface":":4985",
   "log":["REST"],
   "databases":{
      "sync_gateway":{
         "server":"http://localhost:8091",
         "bucket":"sync_gateway",
         "sync":`function(doc) {channel(doc.channels);}`,

    "users": {
        "GUEST": {
          "disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"]
        }
      },

         "shadow": {
            "server": "http://localhost:8091",
            "bucket": "copy"
         }
      }`enter code here`
   }
}
```

but  I am not able to do shadowing...showing following error

2016-06-30T17:54:57.013+05:30 WARNING: Database "sync_gateway": unable to connec
t to external bucket for shadowing: 502 Unable to connect to shadow bucket: No b
ucket named copy -- rest.(*ServerContext)._getOrAddDatabaseFromConfig() at serve
r_context.go:793

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdruQ.png)

Comment: Do you know what shadowing is?  Your naming conventions suggest otherwise.  It's for shimming in existing data, not making a backup of existing data.

Comment: What i hv considered is , shodowing is used for replication the data in another bucket, if we try to shadow data then copy bucket( bucket metion in shadow , in config.json) will get copy of sync_gateway bucket (as per my config.json) correct me if m wrong...

Comment: That will happen as a consequence, but it is not the goal.  The goal of bucket shadowing is to make an existing data source available to sync gateway (because if it predates sync gateway it won't have the proper metadata).  I would say you don't need to use it.

Comment: yaah, got it ...thanx